# AJAX, jQuery HTTP Post, no data being recieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, curl, asp.net-web-api

I've looked at many similar questions on here, but I am unable to get to the bottom of this issue.

I've built a Web API, and if I post at it using curl as follows:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"password":"abcd"}' http://<ip>:5000/api/v1.0/state
```

My API receives the message and records:

```
<Request 'http://<ip>:5000/api/v1.0/state' [POST]>
{u'password': u'abcd'}
192.168.1.100 - - [08/Feb/2016 21:04:32] "POST /api/v1.0/stateHTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So far so good....

I've built a webpage with the following code (I am brand new to web dev), which I am using to post against this API:

```
function myFunction() {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://" + document.domain + ":5000/api/v1.0/state",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data: {"password" : "John"},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});

}
```

When calling this function, the post is clearly recieved by my API, but without any data:

```
<Request 'http://<ip>:5000/api/v1.0/state' [POST]>
None
192.168.1.120 - - [08/Feb/2016 21:09:53] "POST /api/v1.0/state HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I've tried using a $.post method:

```
$.post(
"http://" + document.domain + ":5000/api/v1.0/state",
JSON.stringify({"password" : "password" }) ,
function(data) {
    alert("Response: " + data);
 }
);
```

And I get the same result.

**EDIT: Tried using the following code, as suggested by an answer below:**

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://" + document.domain + ":5000/api/v1.0/state",
   method: "POST",
   dataType:"json",
   contentType:'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify({"password" : "John"}),
   success: function(data){
       alert(data);
   }
```

});

And I receive an OPTIONS API response:

```
192.168.1.120 - - [08/Feb/2016 21:31:28] "OPTIONS /api/v1.0/state HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Any thoughts? I'm able to hit the server, but can't get any JSON data across.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By your curl snippet it looks like your endpoint is expecting a JSON request payload. jQuery does not set a content-type request header of `application/json`, so you have to actually tell it to do so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://" + document.domain + ":5000/api/v1.0/state",
    method: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"password" : "John"}),
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Also note if this is being used on a different domain, meaning not `"http://" + document.domain + ":5000`, you may end up hitting a CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information, strangely enough when I post I now see an OPTIONS method in my API logs:                                                                              192.168.1.120 - - [08/Feb/2016 21:31:28] "OPTIONS /api/v1.0/stateHTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: I did also hit the CORS issue with GET methods against my API, and I used a python flask CORS module to get around the issue (API is built using python flask).

Comment: I've done a bit of googling, and the OPTIONS response appears to be a pre flight message, prior to sending the POST, looks like I may need to build in OPTIONS request support.